# xcode product clear not clearing the issue viewer

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings

On XCode I do a build and it adds issues in the issue viewer, with warnings and error(s).

In the past I did `Product | Clean` and my issues list was cleared (made empty). But now it shows a message "Clean succeeded" and the warnings are still there!

Is this a bug, or is there some setting?
I'm using XCode Version: 9.4.0 according to the help/XCode-help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It was a list of problems with the current versions of the build, after upgrading the XCODE which now works only with more advanced versions of Android.

I followed the recommendations (and ruined my project which cannot be built) but that cleared all the issues. I then returned with an old batch, ignore all the warnings and build happily ever after.